# iOS background fetch. Feching Firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have problem fetching data from Firebase database. My background fetching works since i can track it all the way down to the **observeSingleEventOfType:withBlock** which doesn't get called only in the background state.

Now im wondering does anyone know if fetching Firebase database is allowed in background state of the app?

Comment: Yes It does perform background work. I have enabled it.

Answer (score 1):

Allowed? What do you mean? Allowed by Apple?

Apple has OS support for background downloading with `NSURLSession` (or `URLSession` in Swift 3.) If your downloading code doesn't use `URLSession` then I don't think it's possible to download from the background. (You're only allowed to do a small list of things from the background.)

Comment: Are you writing the iOS code, or are you using FireBase iOS frameworks? (I've barely touched Firebase, and that was on somebody else's project, so I don't know a lot about it.)

Comment: An app can download in the background using NSURLConnection instead of URLSession, but obviously doesn't have the additional benefits that URLSession can provide, however it may not need them. Anyway just saying, its not essential to use URLSession for background downloading.

Comment: NSURLSession was deprecated in iOS 9 and shouldn't be used for new development.

Comment: Of course. But op has some existing code, and you stated you didn't think its possible to download in the background if not using URLSession, which isn't the case. So pointing out that using NSURLConnection instead of URLSession would not be a cause for downloading not to work (whether the download data amount can complete within a background timeframe using NSURLConnection is a possibility of course).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up calling **FIRDatabase.database().reference()** from **AppDelegate** and it worked! Not sure why it wasnt working while i was trying to call it from **window?.rootViewController as? MapViewController** i could track using break points that the code reaches **observeSingleEventOfType:withBlock** but still have no idea why it wasnt being called.

Comment: Add the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question (there's an edit button under it) to increase your chance of getting help with this.