Flutter: Firestore server unavailable from background
I want to sync my firestore data from background once a FCM message is received. Therefore I want to fetch data from firestore server only using GetOptions(source: Source.server), because server data could have changed.
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  
 final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

// Throws firestore/unavailable when reading from server
var tasks = await _firestore.collection('tasks').get(GetOptions(source: Source.server)
);
return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
  final data = doc.data();
  Task task = Task.fromJson(data);
  return task;
}).toList();
  
}

Problem
Once the (iOS) app is in background, I get the error firestore/unavailable, only reading from firestore cache is working. Is this an iOS related issue? Do background processes not have internet access or do I have to set a specific permission?
My iOS app uses the following Background modes:

Background fetch
Background processing
Remote notifications


Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884637/ios-background-fetch-feching-firebase-database? This also looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57772226/background-mode-firebase-fetch-data-swift

The issue seems to be resolved, but I don't exactly know what of the following actually fixed it:

Update iOS to 17.5.1
Update flutter to 3.22.1
Disable an ad-block VPN
Add retry with backoff logic

  Future<T> retry<T>(Future<T> Function() function, {int maxRetries = 5, Duration delayFactor = const Duration(seconds: 2)}) async {
      int attempt = 0;
      while (true) {
        try {
          return await function();
        } catch (e) {
          if (++attempt > maxRetries) {
            rethrow;
          }
          await Future.delayed(delayFactor * attempt);
        }
      }
  }  

  var tasks = await retry(() => firestore.getAllTasks());

